# How do I move a Qt form class to another namespace?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class derived from QDialog that is currently in the global namespace and I want to move it to my project namespace.  I tried the "Change objectName" function in Qt Designer, but it doesn't let me type the colon character.

Answer (score 2):

So, a few more minutes of trying and I figured it out.  In designer, enter edit mode on the class name in the object tree.  Prepend the class name with the desired namespace along with the scope operator and it will update the .ui file.  You then have to manually update the associated header file by wrapping everything in the new namespace.

E.g. rename `MyClass` to `ProjName::MyClass` in designer, then make the header look like this:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace MyProject {

namespace Ui {
class MyClass;
}

class MyClass : public QDialog
{/*...*/};


}

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```